# Python nested class confusion

Tags: python, lambda, stream, nested-class

I am studying the idea about lazy evaluation. This is the `Stream` class I am having trouble with: [refer to 4.2.6 Stream](http://composingprograms.com/pages/42-implicit-sequences.html)

```
class Stream:
  """A lazily computed linked list.""" 

  class Empty:
      def __repr__(self):
          return 'Stream.empty'
  empty = Empty()

  def __init__(self, first, compute_rest= lambda: empty):
      assert callable(compute_rest), 'compute_rest must be callable.'
      self.first = first
      self._compute_rest = compute_rest

  @property
  def rest(self):
      """Return the rest of the stream, computing it if necessary."""
      if self._compute_rest is not None:
          self._rest = self._compute_rest()
          self._compute_rest = None
      return self._rest

  def __repr__(self):
      return 'Stream({0}, <...>)'.format(repr(self.first))
```

Then I create a toy `Stream` for testing:

`s = Stream(1, lambda: Stream(2+3, lambda: Stream(9)))`

I want to know what will happen when I reach the end of `Stream`, so I do:

`s.rest.rest.rest`

What I expect is the screen to print out `Stream.empty` since the last element is `lambda: empty`, but I got error traceback message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-64cf45661094> in <module>()
----> 1 s.rest.rest.rest

<ipython-input-4-7cc49730db55> in rest(self)
     16         """Return the rest of the stream, computing it if necessary."""
     17         if self._compute_rest is not None:
---> 18             self._rest = self._compute_rest()
     19             self._compute_rest = None
     20         return self._rest

<ipython-input-4-7cc49730db55> in <lambda>()
      7     empty = Empty()
      8 
----> 9     def __init__(self, first, compute_rest= lambda: empty):
     10         assert callable(compute_rest), 'compute_rest must be callable.'
     11         self.first = first

NameError: name 'empty' is not defined
```

So my question is, I do have my `empty` defined as a class variable, but the interpreter says it is not defined. If I take the `Empty` class definition out of nested class to the global frame, the code works.

Do I understand how nested class work wrong?
Anyone please give me a hint. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "I do have my empty defined as a class variable", but then you're trying to access it a normal variable, use: `Stream.empty`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thank you, straight to the point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in that post is invalid and broken. The `lambda` will look up the name `empty` in a parent scope. The problem here then is that a class body is *not a scope nestable scope*, so only the global scope remains for the lookup.

From the [*Execution Model* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods

It doesn't matter here that the `lambda` is not a method but a callable bound as a default value for an argument for a method.

You can reference it using the class name instead:

```
def __init__(self, first, compute_rest= lambda: Stream.empty):
```

because `Stream` is now a global (set by running the `class` statement).

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.  Very helpful.